# How to use an object orientated approach to creating a character for a text based game

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to learn object-orientated programming with python in creating a simple text-based game. I am currently struggling as a newcomer to this coding approach.

So my idea was to create a sub-class of character to include things like the "stats" as shown in the code below, which would be determined by the "Race" of the character during character creation. For context, the Races will included Dwarf, Elf, Human, Orc.

As seen by my failed attempt I'm clearly missing a vital piece of information to fix what I am doing here. Unfortunately, I imagined the internet to be full of python games yet most don't use an object-orientated approach of which I am trying to learn.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, playerName, playerGender, playerRace, playerFaction):
        self.playerName = playerName
        self.playerGender = playerGender
        self.playerRace = playerRace
        self.playerFaction = playerFaction
        self.playerStats = []

    def setPlayerStats(self, mining, manufacturing, exploration, invention, trading):
        self.mining = 0
        self.manufacturing = 0
        self.exploration = 0
        self.invention = 0 
        self.trading = 0
        self.playerStats.append(setPlayerStats)
```

I`m looking for an object-orientated way to group the "Stats" to the character class but unfortunately, my research (probably to do with my lack of understanding) has stumped me and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the race classes you extended from `Character` for context? If you are going to use inheritance you don't need to declare a `playerRace` attribute as it will be the name of your child class.

Comment: I have not managed to get that far as my current issue is with storing a subset of classes in my character class for the Race Faction Stats and Gender. For some context, however, the Race will include Dwarf[3,1,0,1,0] ~ relating to the "Stats" and that is as far as the concept extends for that part thus far.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you will need to modify your base class and do something in the lines of the following (attribute names are changed to better conform to PEP8):

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, faction):
        self.player_name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.faction = faction
        self.set_player_stats()

    def _set_player_stats(self, mining, manufacturing, exploration, invention, trading):
        self.mining = mining
        self.manufacturing = manufacturing
        self.exploration = exploration
        self.invention = invention
        self.trading = trading

    def set_player_stats(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Dwarf(Character):
    def set_player_stats(self):
        self._set_player_stats(3, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

then you can do the following:

```
>>> john_the_dwarf = Dwarf("John Doe", "M", "Foo Faction")
>>> john_the_dwarf.mining
3
```

Comment: following your example ive slightly modified it to somewhat show what I'm trying to do
 
`def setPlayerRace(dwarf, elf, human, orc):
        self.dwarf = dwarf
        self.elf = elf
        self.human = human
        self.orc = orc

    def playerRace(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class playerRace(Character):
    def playerRace(self):
        self.setPlayerRace()`

Something to that extent if you follow what I'm trying to do here. As I lack the technical terms it's hard to put across what I'm implying.

Comment: This is not how object oriented design works. The class itself **is** the race. You don't store the race in a separate attribute.